# How do I merge / decouple times like this in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have downtime data with 2 machine IDs (333 & 334).  The downtime comes in separately, but I need to transform it such that:

- When both machines are down, the duration counts towards 100% of the duration
- When only ONE machine is down, the duration counts towards 50% of the duration

```
    declare table @Data (DTID integer, machineID integer, startTime datetime, endTime datetime, duration float)
    
    insert into @Data (DTID, machineID, startTime, endTime, duration)
    values
    (1,333,'2023-09-21 11:00:00','2023-09-21 11:15:00',15.0),
    (2,334,'2023-09-21 11:05:00','2023-09-21 11:10:00',5.0),
    (3,333,'2023-09-21 11:17:00','2023-09-21 11:18:00',1.0),
    (4,334,'2023-09-21 11:16:00','2023-09-21 11:20:00',4.0)
```

and turn it into the following transformation (where 999 = both machined down during the same time period, 100% duration counts):

```
    insert into @Data (DTID, machineID, startTime, endTime, duration)
    values
    (1,333,'2023-09-21 11:00:00','2023-09-21 11:05:00',2.5),
    (2,999,'2023-09-21 11:05:00','2023-09-21 11:10:00',5.0),
    (3,333,'2023-09-21 11:10:00','2023-09-21 11:15:00',2.5),
    (4,334,'2023-09-21 11:16:00','2023-09-21 11:17:00',0.5),
    (5,999,'2023-09-21 11:17:00','2023-09-21 11:18:00',1.0)
    (5,334,'2023-09-21 11:18:00','2023-09-21 11:20:00',1.0)
```

I just can't wrap my head around what to do. If using the first table, it would look like the line is down for 15+5+1+4=25 minutes.  But, in reality since both machines are not always down, it would be more like the second table: 2.5+5+2.5+0.5+1+1=12.5 minutes.  That is quite a difference.

Comment: As an aside, `FLOAT` is a terrible choice for a datatype to store a proper value, you should be using `DECIMAL`. (Not sure if you realised that `VALUES` is plural and can insert multiple values?). And best practice is to list the columns being inserted into.

Comment: Isn't it easiest to just keep the machines online

Comment: First, you need to identify all unique start and end times from the data. These will be your points of interest where the status of machines might change. Then you should determine Machine Status for Each Interval: For each interval between two consecutive points of interest, determine which machines were down. And finally adjust Duration, based on the number of machines that were down during each interval, adjust the duration.

Comment: @DaleK - I didn't design the table structure, just reading from it.  I can't change it to float as that was the design structure of this massive database.  MachineID is just a column name I chose to represent what was in the table and try to make it sound more readable than what it originally was.

Comment: @siggemannen - hilarious :)

Comment: @JimmyKurian - I do understand that much, just not how to accomplish this.

Comment: @DaleK - gotcha, that was an accident.  The code I tested to show how to create that table was in SQL Server in a VM that I could not copy out of, so manually typed.

Comment: Is it max 2 machines or there can be more than 2 ?

Comment: Note that the total sum of 'downtime' can be taken as the sum of downtimes of individual machines, divided by 2 (e.g., for each minute down, a machine contributes 1/2 a minute of downtime. If both are down, it counts as a full minute). Furthermore, it holds true in your data as your last data line (line 5) is incorrect - it should be `(5, 999, 11:17, 11:18, 1)` and `(6, 334, 11:18, 11:20, 1)` which gives a total of `2.5 + 5 + 2.5 + 0.5 + 1 + 1 = 12.5` - which is half the total of minutes down individually.

Comment: @Squirrel - it is max 2 machines

Comment: @seanb - you are correct, I did mess up the splitting of those downtime(s) on the last 1.  And, while it does equal to 12.5 which is half of 25, it would not always be equivalent.  Plus, I have to be able to show the details, which means I can't just divide in half, I have to split and display each downtime split accurately.

Answer (score 0):

Not perfect solution, should works for your 2 machines scenario.

`cte1` flattens the `start` and `end` datetime into single `datetime` with a indicator flag (+1 for start and -1 for end). `cnt` is to count number of overlapping date range by performing a cumulative sum on the `flag`.

`cte2` determines the `endDatetime` and ignoring those line with `cnt = 2`

In the final query, the machineID determinitation is sort of hardcoded with an case expression.

```
with 
cte1 as
(
  select d.DTID, d.machineID, a.flag, a.dt, 
         cnt = sum(flag) over (order by dt, machineID)
  from   #Data d
         cross apply
         (
             values
             (+1, d.startTime),
             (-1, d.endTime)
         ) a (flag, dt)
),
cte2 as
(
  select *,
          startTime = dt,
          endTime   = case when cnt <> 0
                           then lead(dt) over (order by dt, flag)
                           end
  from   cte1
)
select DTID, 
       machineID = case when cnt  = 2 
                        then 999 
                        when flag = -1 
                        then case when c.machineID= 333 then 334 else 333 end
                        else machineID end, 
       startTime, endTime,
       duration = datediff(minute, startTime, endTime) 
                * case when cnt = 1 then 0.5 else 1 end 
from   cte2 c
where  endTime is not null
order by dt, machineID
```

[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/KBGAtwEz)

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternative approach from @Squirrel's.

If you just need the answer you've asked for (e.g., the streaks) then their answer is preferable.

However, my approach is to first transform the data into something that you can easily do other things with. It also makes it very easy to add multiple machines (will just need to expand on the IDs in a few places).

It does this by first creating the data table that has a row for each minute and machine that is down
e.g.,

```
Down_Minute             machineID
----------------------- -----------
2023-09-21 11:00:00     333
2023-09-21 11:01:00     333
2023-09-21 11:02:00     333
2023-09-21 11:03:00     333
2023-09-21 11:04:00     333
2023-09-21 11:05:00     333
2023-09-21 11:05:00     334
2023-09-21 11:06:00     333
2023-09-21 11:06:00     334
2023-09-21 11:07:00     333
etc...
```

The above table makes it easy to do other calculations. Note though that this assumes you are interested only down to the minute. There are 1440 minutes in a day, which makes this process reasonably efficient. If you decided to go to seconds, you'd have to review it for efficiency (and change the smalldatetime field to datetime or similar).

The processing is shown in [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/nP5qoS6D). The original data is in a table called #Data, and I use a numbers table (0..100k) called #Nums.

The code to split the above into individual minutes is straightforward

```
CREATE TABLE #DT (Down_Minute smalldatetime, machineID int, PRIMARY KEY (Down_Minute, machineID));

INSERT INTO #DT (Down_Minute, machineID)
    SELECT  DATEADD(minute, #Nums.n, #Data.startTime) AS Down_Minute, #Data.machineID
    FROM    #Data
            CROSS JOIN #Nums
    WHERE   #Nums.n < #Data.duration;
```

Now, you can do simple reports i.e.,

- Number of machines down each minute

```
SELECT      Down_Minute, COUNT(*) AS Num_Machines_Down
    FROM    #DT
    GROUP BY Down_Minute
    ORDER BY Down_Minute;
/*
Down_Minute             Num_Machines_Down
----------------------- -----------------
2023-09-21 11:00:00     1
2023-09-21 11:01:00     1
2023-09-21 11:02:00     1
2023-09-21 11:03:00     1
2023-09-21 11:04:00     1
2023-09-21 11:05:00     2
2023-09-21 11:06:00     2
2023-09-21 11:07:00     2
2023-09-21 11:08:00     2
2023-09-21 11:09:00     2
2023-09-21 11:10:00     1
2023-09-21 11:11:00     1
2023-09-21 11:12:00     1
2023-09-21 11:13:00     1
2023-09-21 11:14:00     1
2023-09-21 11:16:00     1
2023-09-21 11:17:00     2
2023-09-21 11:18:00     1
2023-09-21 11:19:00     1
*/
```

- Which machines are down each minute

```
SELECT      p.Down_Minute, p.[333], p.[334] 
    FROM    (SELECT Down_Minute, machineID FROM #DT) A
            PIVOT (COUNT(machineID) FOR machineID IN ([333],[334])) p
/*
Down_Minute             333         334
----------------------- ----------- -----------
2023-09-21 11:00:00     1           0
2023-09-21 11:01:00     1           0
2023-09-21 11:02:00     1           0
2023-09-21 11:03:00     1           0
2023-09-21 11:04:00     1           0
2023-09-21 11:05:00     1           1
2023-09-21 11:06:00     1           1
2023-09-21 11:07:00     1           1
2023-09-21 11:08:00     1           1
2023-09-21 11:09:00     1           1
2023-09-21 11:10:00     1           0
2023-09-21 11:11:00     1           0
2023-09-21 11:12:00     1           0
2023-09-21 11:13:00     1           0
2023-09-21 11:14:00     1           0
2023-09-21 11:16:00     0           1
2023-09-21 11:17:00     1           1
2023-09-21 11:18:00     0           1
2023-09-21 11:19:00     0           1
*/
```

You can also take a 'gaps and islands' approach to create the 'streaks' (You will probably need to look up the approach. Here I have broken out all the steps separately, to be easier to understand - but you can combine them easily).

```
CREATE TABLE #DM (Down_Minute smalldatetime PRIMARY KEY, [333] int, [334] int, NewGrp_flag tinyint, GroupNum int);

INSERT INTO #DM (Down_Minute, [333], [334])
    SELECT  p.Down_Minute, p.[333], p.[334] 
    FROM    (SELECT Down_Minute, machineID FROM #DT) A
            PIVOT (COUNT(machineID) FOR machineID IN ([333],[334])) p;

WITH DM_NewGrp AS
        (SELECT Down_Minute, NewGrp_flag,
                CASE WHEN LAG(Down_Minute, 1) OVER (ORDER BY Down_Minute) = DATEADD(minute, -1, Down_Minute)
                    AND LAG([333], 1) OVER (ORDER BY Down_Minute) = [333]
                    AND LAG([334], 1) OVER (ORDER BY Down_Minute) = [334]
                    THEN 0 ELSE 1 
                    END AS NewGrp_flag_calc
            FROM    #DM
        )
    UPDATE  DM_NewGrp
        SET NewGrp_flag = NewGrp_flag_calc;

WITH DM_GrpNums AS
        (SELECT     Down_Minute, GroupNum,
                    SUM(NewGrp_flag) OVER (ORDER BY Down_Minute) AS GroupNum_calc
            FROM    #DM
        )
    UPDATE  DM_GrpNums
        SET GroupNum = GroupNum_calc;

SELECT      MIN(Down_Minute) AS startDT, MAX(Down_Minute) AS endDT_inclusive,
            [333], [334], [GroupNum]
    FROM    #DM
    GROUP BY [333], [334], [GroupNum]
    ORDER BY [GroupNum];
```

Result

```
startDT                 endDT_inclusive         333         334         GroupNum
----------------------- ----------------------- ----------- ----------- -----------
2023-09-21 11:00:00     2023-09-21 11:04:00     1           0           1
2023-09-21 11:05:00     2023-09-21 11:09:00     1           1           2
2023-09-21 11:10:00     2023-09-21 11:14:00     1           0           3
2023-09-21 11:16:00     2023-09-21 11:16:00     0           1           4
2023-09-21 11:17:00     2023-09-21 11:17:00     1           1           5
2023-09-21 11:18:00     2023-09-21 11:19:00     0           1           6
```

You can also start with the above and do some simple calcultions (e.g., durations, etc) to calculate your desired downtimes

```
WITH Downtimes AS (
    SELECT      MIN(Down_Minute) AS startDT, MAX(Down_Minute) AS endDT_inclusive, 
                [333], [334], [GroupNum]
        FROM    #DM
        GROUP BY [333], [334], [GroupNum]
        )
    SELECT  startDT, endDT_inclusive, [333], [334],
            DATEDIFF(minute, startDT, endDT_inclusive) + 1 AS Duration_down,
            CASE WHEN [333]=1 AND [334]=1 THEN 999
                WHEN [333] = 1 THEN 333
                ELSE 334 
                END AS MachineID,
            ([333] + [334]) *  (DATEDIFF(minute, startDT, endDT_inclusive) + 1) * 0.5 AS Downtime
    FROM    Downtimes
    ORDER BY startDT;
```

Results

```
startDT                 endDT_inclusive         333         334         Duration_down MachineID   Downtime
----------------------- ----------------------- ----------- ----------- ------------- ----------- ---------------------------------------
2023-09-21 11:00:00     2023-09-21 11:04:00     1           0           5             333         2.5
2023-09-21 11:05:00     2023-09-21 11:09:00     1           1           5             999         5.0
2023-09-21 11:10:00     2023-09-21 11:14:00     1           0           5             333         2.5
2023-09-21 11:16:00     2023-09-21 11:16:00     0           1           1             334         0.5
2023-09-21 11:17:00     2023-09-21 11:17:00     1           1           1             999         1.0
2023-09-21 11:18:00     2023-09-21 11:19:00     0           1           2             334         1.0
```